# Convert Videos In Ubuntu

Tags: video, video-conversion

I want to convert videos to `3GP` format? So is there any good tool available to convert this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg tool.

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

then what you can do is read this on how to use it

[How to use ffmpeg](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-FFmpeg)

So it would be

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile <filename>.3gp
```

For more options, you can read more on it. If you want to use a GUI based tool, you can use

[Win FF](http://winff.org/html_new/)